# django templates url parse error

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I am trying to construct a URL in the template as shown but it ends up getting the following error. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

`'url' requires a non-empty first argument. The syntax changed in Django 1.5, see the docs.`

urls.py

```
url(r'^launch$', views.LaunchInstanceView.as_view(), name='launch')
```

templates :

```
<a href="{%url launch %}" >Launch</a>
```

I've also tried

urls.py

```
url(r'^launch$', views.LaunchInstanceView.as_view(), name='instance.views.launch')
```

templates :

```
<a href="{%url instances.views.launch %}" >Launch</a>
```

Edit 1:

with quotes get the error as

```
<a href="{%url 'launch' %}" >Launch</a>

Reverse for 'launch' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns(VIEW_MOD,
url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
url(r'^launch$', views.LaunchInstanceView.as_view(), name='launch'),
url(r'^(?P<instance_id>[^/]+)/$',
    views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
)
```

views.py

```
class LaunchInstanceView(workflows.WorkflowView):
   workflow_class = project_workflows.LaunchInstance

   def get_initial(self):
     initial = super(LaunchInstanceView, self).get_initial()
     initial['project_id'] = self.request.user.tenant_id
     initial['user_id'] = self.request.user.id
     return initial
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
<a href="{% url 'launch' %}" >Launch</a>
```

Comment: Sorry i have corrected the question.my mistake its happening after adding  {% %}

Comment: This answer is still valid, the "launch" must be in quotes.

Comment: i tried with quotes and got the following error Reverse for 'launch' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Comment: Change your `urls.py` so the URL pattern has the same `name` as the one you're using in your template. In this case, both should be "launch" and not "instances.views.launch".

Comment: yes i have chnaged and now it has only launch but still getting the same error

Comment: If the code you have posted is exactly the same as the one you're having trouble, then I'm not sure what the problem is. Do you have multiple patterns in your `urls.py` with the same `name`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54781/discussion-between-rajeev-and-matt-deacalion-stevens).

Comment: i have given the full urls.py

Answer (score 0):

You should provide name as 'launch' is your url. 
Please edit that if you want to call url like `<a href="{%url 'launch' %}" >Launch</a>`

```
url(r'^launch$', views.LaunchInstanceView.as_view(), name='launch')
```

if i am getting wrong. Please update your question so i can understand your problem easily.

Answer (score 0):

If the above provied urls.py is you ROOT_URLCONF.. then following should work:

```
url(r'^launch/$', views.LaunchInstanceView.as_view(), name='launch')  #Its a good practice to put '/' at the end of the pattern name, so if someone enters a '/' at the end in the browser it doesn't give 404
```

and

```
<a href="{% url 'launch' %}" >Launch</a>
```

**Otherwise**

Please check your settings.py file and See, to which file ROOT_URLCONF points to.
if it is different and **you are including the above urls.py** in the root urls.py file, then please check if it is **either** being included **using a namespace** e.g

```
 url(r'^xyz/', include('path_to_above_urls.py', namespace='abc')),
```

**or there's some other url with same name** in root urls.py e.g:

```
 url(r'some_pattern$', someview.as_view(), name='launch'),
 url(r'^xyz/', include('path_to_above_urls.py')),
```

In 1st case you will have to access the url with  `{% url 'abc:launch' %}`

In 2nd case you will have to change the name to make it unique.